# Oracle - Writing REST services in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql, oracle12c

I have created a REST service (via APEX) which utilizes PL/SQL to build a result set.  I loop through a large cursor and do a `sys.htp.print(my_data)` – (as an aside, is the `sys.htp.print` the best option here?).  Basically, I am dumping a data string, a row at a time, to the http buffer...

My client process receives the data fine, as long as it is not too big a data set.  For example, the client process can receive data sets of approximately 35K rows, but larger data sets cause issues.

I do NOT have any value set for Pagination Size.  It appears that I will have to implement some type of pagination functionality.  My confusion is HOW to do this with PL/SQL.

In looking at the APEX help popup, it refers to `:row_offset` and `:row_count` variables.  When I have used SQL based queries for REST services (as opposed to PL/SQL) I just set the pagination, and reference the page number that I want.  How is this different for PL/SQL?  Do I continue using the REST Service URL (which basically adds a 'page=1' type of extension to the service URL) as with SQL based services? (i.e. Source Type = Query), or do I need to adjust my code to reference `:row_offset` and `:row_count`?  If so, since this is PL/SQL based, will each call have to run the service, and just return the data greater than  `:row_offset` up to `:row_count`?

Comment: pagination is handled automatically for SQL - it's not for PL/SQL blocks. You'll have to code your plsql to be able to handle said pagination - you'll need to be able to pass in the page number you want - then dynamically getting the records you want for said page, and then tracking if there is another page to get

Comment: Because this is PL/SQL, does that mean that if I need 10 REST calls to retrieve the data, I will need to execute the same process 10 times, and calculate/return each of the 10 "chunks" of data?  I can live with having to make 10 separate calls, but the "do the same work 10 times" is problematic.  How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider reworking your PL/SQL to return the data as a pipelined table function. That allows it to be queried through a query like

```
SELECT columns FROM TABLE(pkg.func(par=> :a)) ORDER BY...
```

That way it can handle the pagination as though it were any other SQL query.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADDCI/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#ADDCI2140

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle 12c we have the new Offset and Fetch clauses in SQL.

SELECT (Required Columns) 
  FROM (Tables)
(Joins/Predicates) 
ORDER BY (Required Columns)
**OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY**;

You may want to check the [OracleDocumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html) and also some code samples [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1).

Comment: While this is great for SQL, it doesn't really help me with the PL/SQL side, as I am building my output, not just using a simple Select statement.